# Postman is throwing "unexpected '<' " error for post request developed in YII2

Tags: yii2

I am getting this for past two days and not able to fix it yet . Any pointers would be appreciated:

```
public function actionInsert()
{
    \Yii:: $app->response->format = \yii\web\Response:: FORMAT_JSON;
    $postData = Yii::$app->request->post();

    $connection = \Yii::$app->db;

    $connection->createCommand()->insert('user', [
        'username' => $postData['$username'],
        'status' => $postData['$status'],
    ])
    ->execute(); 
    return ['status' => true, 'data' => $postData];  
}
```

Comment: that does not explain anything , add your complete error trace

Comment: Hi thanks for your response but that's all it's showing in postman.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud choose name of field without $ symbol on forms. Try this

```
public function actionInsert()
{
    \Yii:: $app->response->format = \yii\web\Response:: FORMAT_JSON;
    $postData = Yii::$app->request->post();

    $connection = \Yii::$app->db;

    $connection->createCommand()->insert('user', [
        'username' => $postData['username'],
        'status' => $postData['status'],
    ])
    ->execute(); 
    return ['status' => true, 'data' => $postData];  
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I am still getting the same issue .

Comment: could you add screenshot of error, I want to show full stack trace ?